# I have a problem with Python dictionary that has strings as keys and very long Numpy arrays as values

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Now, I want to write the dictionary in a .csv file. My problem is that the Numpy arrays (which are the values of my dictionary) are not writen as a whole.
They are writen as abbreviations as in the picture attached. How do I write those values (numpy arrays) as a whole i.e. element by element?

[image]

Comment: Is that a screenshot of the _actual_ csv file, or a screenshot of python `print()` output?

Comment: How are you writing them? If you're not careful, you'll end up with the string representation.

Comment: Are you using a `csv` module, to write dictionary.  For the 2nd column it is just writing the `str(value)`, which for large arrays uses this abbreviation.  And the `[]` as well.  Putting the dictionary in a pandas dataframe will have the same problem.

Comment: Can you `np.vstack` all the values into one 2d array?

Comment: The screenshot is what I'm writing in my csv file. The keys are writen OK but the values i.e. numpy arrays are not writen properly. They are writen as when they appear in the console as they are very long (10000+ elements)

Comment: I'm using the csv module for writing my csv file

Comment: How  do you intend to read or use this file?  It sounds like you want one column with the key values (strings) and a 1000+ columns with floats.  Reconstructing the dictionary, even if the file is written correctly will not be trivial.  Does the file really have to a text csv?  Why not a Python pickle file instead?

Comment: "Now, I want to write the dictionary in a .csv file." Why do you want to use a csv file? What exactly would be the format? CSV is for storing simple, tabular data. Any nested data structure is likely not a good use-case for CSV. consider another serialization format

Comment: @ hpaulj thank you for the suggestion. I might consider pickle